# VBA Pattern Fail When Totally Obvious

Tags: regex, vba, excel, pdf-conversion

When I ctrl-f in a spreadsheet, I can find the text, "child Support," but when I'm using it as a pattern it fails.  Other obvious words work, like "Date," for instance.

This spreadsheet was converted from a PDF.  Could there be some hidden null characters that are causing this column to be ignored?

```
Private Function RegExTest(s As String) As String
    Dim re, match
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    re.Pattern = "(child support)"
    re.Global = True

    For Each match In re.Execute(s)
        MsgBox match.value
        RegExDate = match.value
        Exit For
    Next
    Set re = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Regexes are case-sensitive by default - could that be the problem?

Comment: Also, consider `"(child\s+support)"` as a sanity check.  The whitespace may not be what you think it is.

Comment: I have the right case, and I just tried the \s.... No luck on either.  It's so weird -- literally the cell above it is "Deductions," and when I put that in, it can be found!  All the cell formats are General, too.

Comment: So if you copy and paste the contents of the cell in question into your VBA string (i.e. rather than typing what you see), it still does not match?

Comment: Ok -- no luck.  I also pasted into notepad++.  Don't see any obvious hidden characters.

Comment: Ok -- duh -- sorry to all the Excel power users in the world...  The cell is locked.  I'll figure out in the code to unlock it.  Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Answer your own question, and accept your own answer.  Unless this is address in another question & answer, this may be helpful to someone else.

Comment: Still hacking -- the Locked cells are the issue -- but unlocking them doesn't resolve the issue.  It's like there's a memory of the property or another issue.

Comment: Jeff - I don't know if this is a typo but your function is declared as `RegExTest` and you are stuffing the date into `RegExDate`.

Comment: Ya, this isn't the code I'm using.  Right now, I'm staring at XML trying to figure out what's different between the 'good' and 'bad' cells.

Comment: Add `.ignorecase = true` to your declarations.  Also try `"(child[\s\xA0]+support)"` for your code to look for `NBSP`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that:

```
"child Support"
```

is not the same as:

```
"child support"
```

Comment: Thanks got it.  Not at a dos prompt after all.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Gary's student, regex is case-sensitive. You had fallen in one late binding drawbacks which is the lack of intellisense.

If you had used early binding (Referenced MS VBscript regular expression 5.5 class from your IDE Tools menu > References), you would have seen the regex object had a case sensitive property that be set to true or false thanks to VBA intellisense:

[image]

Comment: Thanks -- that's not the issue... I know this: re.Pattern = "(child support)" is causing a lot of people on the Asbperger's Spectrum a lot of problems because it's in lower case, but that's not the problem. Thanks.  PDFs and Excel is where data goes to die, not manipulated.

Comment: @JeffYoung Can you upload the dysfunctional, converted PDF to a public site and post a link here?

Comment: Sorry, I just had to give up... We had to move on.  I really hate VBA, Excel -- it seems too inconsistent.